# Binary Search using Python

Tags: python, search, binary

I have tried the following Python Algorithm for Binary Search, which is giving me error of a continuous loop when searching for value not in list ,where it should just simply give o/p as "not found" ,the other method i tried is with function which worked well, but function is not allowed to use,i am not getting where mistake is?

```
M = [4,5,6,7,8,9,20,17,45]
print(M)
num = int(input("enter the number: "))
k=True
low=0
high=len(M)-1
mid=(low-high)//2
while low<=high:
print(mid)
if num == M[mid]:
    print("Number found")
    k=False
    break
else:
    if num < M[mid]:
        high = mid
        mid = (low+high)//2
        k=True

    else:
        low=mid
        mid=(mid+high)//2
        k=True

if k==True:
    print("not found")
```

In O/P when displayed

> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 17, 45]
>   enter the number: 
>   if say for E.g i give input as 25 which is giving me infinite loop...

Comment: Your indentation is bad: `while low<=high:` has nothing indented after it, the `break` statement is not in a loop, etc. Please show us the code that actually gives the result you state. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Format your code correctly by copy-and-paste from the original source code, then highlight the code and click the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Hey There are a few mistakes with your code,

```
M = [4,5,6,7,8,9,20,17,45] # Your list is not sorted properly
M.sort()
print(M)
num = int(input("enter the number: "))
k=True
low=0
high=len(M)-1
mid=(low+high)//2 # you used (low-high) which is not the way to find the mid value
while low<=high:
print(mid)
if num == M[mid]:
    print("Number found")
    k=False
    break
else:
    if num < M[mid]:
        high = mid - 1 # don't need to consider the mid value again
        mid = (low+high)//2
        k=True #you don't need to use this statement every loop

    else:
        low=mid + 1 # no need to consider mid again
        mid=(low+high)//2 # should be low not mid
        k=True

if k==True:
    print("not found")
```

Hope this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
M = [4,5,6,7,8,9,20,17,45]
M.sort() # added sort
print(M)

num = int(input("enter the number: "))
k=True
low=0
high=len(M)-1

while low<high:
  mid=(high+low)//2 # better place for mid calculating

  if num == M[mid]:
    print("Number found")
    k=False # one k is enough in this while
    break
  else:
    if num < M[mid]:
      high = mid-1 # you don't need to recheck the mid value in future
    else:
      low = mid+1 # you don't need to recheck the mid value in future

if k==True:
  print("not found")
```